# Tomcat continua a mostrar arquivos antigos

Tags: tomcat

Atualizo os arquivos (html, javascript), mas quando acesso o `index.html`, os arquivos não estão como deveriam, lá mostra uma página totalmente diferente, mais antiga, sendo que o arquivo dessa página nem existe mais, já tentei limpar o cache do navegador, reiniciar o servidor, usar o Tomcat do Xampp, deletar a pasta work e nenhum funcionou, continua mostrando a mesma página antiga.
O que devo fazer para o servidor mostrar os arquivos novos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pare todas as instâncias do Tomcat no seu computador e desinstale o Tomcat (se instalado).
Então apague todos os diretórios que pertenciam ao Tomcat (diretórios do Tomcat e aplicativos) e reinstale o Tomcat.

Aconselho a você baixar o eclipse e instalar o Tomcat por lá mesmo, já que você poderá gerenciar a sua instalação do Tomcat pelo próprio eclipse.

UPDATE: Depois de um pouco de pesquisa, minha outra solução é:

- Parar o Tomcat;
- Deletar a pasta do seu projeto que está na raíz do container (geralmente é "webapps/SEU_PROJETO");
- Colocar o .war novo do seu projeto na raíz do container;
- Iniciar novamente o Tomcat

Porquê deveria funcionar:

> Os servidores de aplicação Java tem uma tecnologia que se chama "publish". Quando você invoca o "publish", o servidor deleta tudo o que foi deletado da sua pasta de trabalho e inclui arquivos novos ou modificados para o container. Infelizmente nunca usei o tomcat sem IDE, então não sei como efetuar o "publish" nele sem o Eclipse.

Comment: Inclusive as do Xampp?

Comment: Inclusive as do XAMPP.
Só uma pergunta, qual é seu sistema operacional?

Comment: MS Windows 8.1.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com algumas novas informações, espero que seja útil!

Comment: Argh, a única coisa que funcionou foi reinstalar o Tomcat, mas é inviável fazer isso a cada 5 minutos. O que mata é eu não saber o motivo disso estar acontecendo.

Comment: Pois é, nunca vi isso acontecer antes, nem quando eu usava Windows para desenvolvimento web. Porque você não usa IDEs?

Comment: Não é legal depender de IDEs, é quase como um vício, quando não as tem disponível o pessoal fica perdido.